# canvas.toDataURL() not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas

I get a perfect dataURI in Firefox but not in Chrome. In Chrome, it's just just the original blank canvas. What is wrong? *(I need to generate the image on the page itself).*

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="rasterizeHTML.allinone.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button id="run">Run!</button>
    <div id="newcontent">Content example</div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800" ></canvas>

    <script>
    $('#run').click(function(){
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var newcontent = document.getElementById("newcontent").innerHTML;
      console.log(newcontent);
      rasterizeHTML.drawHTML(newcontent, canvas);

      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

      canvas.src = canvas;
      canvas.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';

      var imgData = canvas.toDataURL();
      console.log(imgData);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Disable all extensions that may interact with the page. Anything that is not from the same domain will taint the canvas despite setting cross domain to anonymous.

Comment: @Blindman67, went into Chrome Incognito mode and it still didn't work. Any more thoughts? Also, the canvas isn't saying it's tainted when i Set the crossOrigin to anonymous.

Comment: Incognito does not mean all extensions are disabled. Try starting chrome with `--disable-web-security` and see if it works. If it does then you have to track down what is tainting the canvas. If it still does not work then you have a problem with rasterizer. There are no particular Chrome issue I am aware of, but it would pay to go to their site and check.

Comment: Thanks, Blindman67! Seems to not solve the problem though

Comment: not sure what rasterize does, but cnavas element has no src and no crossOrigin attribute. Aren't you trying to do it on an `<img>` element?

Comment: @Kaiido It paints a canvas with a DOM element, i.e. <div id="newcontent">Content example</div>, which you can pull the Data URI using toDataURL and set the img rc with that. Problem is, toDataURL works properly in FF but not Chrome.